# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator

Tags: sbt, guava, cassandra-2.0

I am seeing the below exception when creating a Cassandra Cluster object using java client.

```
 val cluster = Cluster.builder().
    withProtocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.V3).
    addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").
    build()
```

The exceptions says `com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator` method not found. But the library(guava) is added to the classPath.

```
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;
[error]     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.makeExecutor(Cluster.java:1100)
[error]     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.access$700(Cluster.java:62)
[error]     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.<init>(Cluster.java:1160)
[error]     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.<init>(Cluster.java:1110)
[error]     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:118)
[error]     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:105)
[error]     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:174)
[error]     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1075)
```

show fullClasspath - contains guava

```
Attributed(/home/kiranraj/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-16.0.1.jar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update guava to the lastest version.
You can also check if is conflicting with any other JAR.